# Understanding the following neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I've currently started reading on online book written by Michael Nielson which in depth talks about the fundementals of creating a neural network as well as giving explained code examples.

The online book I am referring to can be viewed [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com)

I've been following along and created a basic neural network that implements *stochastic gradient descent* to allow the weights and biases to be slightly altered for improved learning accuracy.

The code is about 75 lines long (minus the commenting) and can be seen [here.](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py)

I've used the MNIST [dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) which consists of 60,000 digits which i'm using to train the network.

The SGD function takes `training_data` which is a list of tuples `(x, y)` representing the training inputs and corresponding desired outputs as well as other parameters which are self explanatory.

When creating an instance of the network in the Python shell I load the MNIST dataset as input and use it to adjust the weights and values.

Upon completion of training, i'm a little confused of how to actually *test* the network on other digit inputs which are not part of the dataset.

Am I correct in thinking that I should call the `feedforward` function and input a matrix of my digit glyph?

```
def feedforward(self, a):
        """Return the output of the network if "a" is input."""
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
        return a
```

> It is assumed that the input a is an (n, 1) Numpy ndarray, not a (n, ) vector. Here, n is the number of inputs to the network.

The book talks a lot about how to train the network and i'm just a little confused of how to run some validation tests and get some network output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The output of the `feedforward` function will be a probability distribution over the different outcomes of the network. Check the `evaluate()` function that is defined in the code you shared to see how it might be used.

Comment: I thought as much. I'll give it a go now. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: On a side note... Each time I create an instance of 'Network' will I have to re-train on the data-set to obtain the correct weights/biases before running external tests? Or is there a way I can save the current weights/biases

Comment: You can save the network using pickle or a similar technology.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into it :D